# Artifactory retention set but not deleteBuildArtifacts, what happens?

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, cicd

When uploading artifacts to JFrog artifactory, one might set the retention to e.g. a maximum number of days. On can also set the boolean `deleteBuildArtifacts: true`. If not setting the latter, what will happen after the retention time has passed? Will the garbage cleaning take care of the artifacts next time it runs?

```
def server = Artifactory.server(...)
def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
buildInfo.retention maxDays: 10
server.upload(..., buildInfo)
server.publishBuildInfo(buildInfo)
```

I have read [the scripted pipeline syntax documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax) about the Triggering Build Retention, but could not find the answer.

The reason I'm asking, apart from being curious, is because the user uploading the artifacts does not / should not have DELETE/OVERWRITE permission (there can however be other service users having it).

Answer (score 3):

If `deleteBuildArtifacts` set to false, the artifacts should not be deleted when the retention time passes.
Instead, only the Build Info will be deleted.

For more information:

- [Control Build Retention](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ControlBuildRetention)
- [Artifactory Cleanup Best Practices](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-cleanup-best-practices/) - see good explanation under "Deleting Unused Artifacts"
- [What is Build-Info?](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Build+Integration#BuildIntegration-WhatisBuild-Info?) - information about the Build Info concept